# R - How to find the first cell that is not empty in a column starting from a specific row

Tags: r, lookup

I have inputs and related outputs that happen on later moments. Sometimes 1 input might result in several outputs. I would like to have the input and the first output related to this input in the same row (on the time moment of the input). Therefore I will have to find the first cell that is not empty starting from the row of the input time.

This is my dataset:

```
time    event   result_of event
11:15   input1  
11:16       
11:17       
11:18       output1
11:19       
11:20       output2
11:21   input2  
11:22       output3
11:23       
11:24   input3  
11:25       
11:26       output4
11:27   input4  
11:28       
11:29       output5
```

And this is my desired outcome:

```
time    event   result_of event
11:15   input1  output1
11:16       
11:17       
11:18       
11:19       
11:20       
11:21   input2  output3
11:22       
11:23       
11:24   input3  output4
11:25       
11:26       
11:27   input4  output5
11:28       
11:29
```

The code should be flexible in a sense that there might be a lot of rows between input and output, so it should always check for non-empty cells starting from the current row and going till the last row.

Thank you on beforehand!

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: Specifically, can you post (in your question) the output of `dput(mydata)` (where `mydata` is your data frame). That will make it much easier for us to load your data in our R sessions.

Comment: @RonakShah see below

Comment: @Martijn are you attempting to open a Windows .csv file to Linux.  I ask because your problem looks similar to one I had in the paste.  If so, read this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206918/trouble-with-horizontial-merge-of-csv-files-under-cygwin

Comment: @JacobH; No actually I want to do manupulations on the third column as explained. Everything comes from one dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the data
lines = readLines("file.txt")

# get the input and output line numbers
inputs = grep(".{8}i", lines)
outputs = grep(".{12}o", lines)

# find the first output after each input
n_inputs = length(inputs)
outputs1 = vector(length = n_inputs)
for (x in 1:n_inputs) {
  outputs1[x] = outputs[which(outputs > inputs[x])[1]]
}

# rearrange the data
outputs_text = substr(lines[outputs1], 13, 19)
lines[inputs] = paste0(lines[inputs], outputs_text)
lines[-inputs] = substr(lines[-inputs], 1, 5)

lines[1] = "time    event   result_of event"
writeLines(lines, "newfile.text")
```